# Disable RegisterOnSubmitStatement for specific buttons

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, client-side-validation

I have a RegisterOnSubmitStatement that takes a method name plus validation group. The problem that I am having is that no matter what button I push on the page, the client side validation is getting checked. I only want it to run if the button pushed is part of that validation group.

So in my c# code, I have this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Page, Page.GetType(), "loadingHandler",
"AlwaysFireBeforeFormSubmit('loginControl')");
    }
```

And that calls the following javascript function:

```
function AlwaysFireBeforeFormSubmit(validationGroup) {
    if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
        var isPageValid = Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
        if (isPageValid) {
            modals.showPleaseWait();
        }
    } else {
        modals.showPleaseWait();
    }
}
```

Now, no matter what button with a postback is called, this will get fired for the validation group specified.

Ideally, this would only be fired if the button is within the validation group specified. I'd even be happy if I could find out which button fired the event so that I can check the href to see if it contains, "WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions" in the href. If it does, run validation, otherwise skip it and shop the please wait modal.

Thoughts? Questions? Am I crazy?

-C